# How is the Cost Function of a neural network defined?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, backpropagation

I was reading [Michael Nielson's book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html) on Neural Networks in which he writes that:

> The first assumption we need is that the cost function can be written as an average $C=\sum_x{C_x}$ over cost functions $C_x$ for individual training examples, $x$.

I am unable to understand this assumption. Do any functions exist for which the average over each training example won't exist?

I am unable to grasp how this condition is supposed to be assumed since any function can be average over the training examples.

Comment: There are credible cases where this assumption does not work, for example a cost function proportional to the largest absolute error, and other cases where it needs a transformation to work, for example a cost function proportional to the the square root of the mean of the squares of the errors (just square this and you get to the example in the link).

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the quick response, but I am unable to understand what you wrote.

Comment: Suppose $C= \max_x C_x$; this fails the assumption.  Or suppose $C=\sqrt{\frac1n \sum_x C_x^2}$ as the root-mean-square; this also fails the assumption but can be monotonically transformed to $K=\frac1n \sum_x K_x$ where $K=C^2$ and $K_x=C_x^2$ and will then work with the assumption

Comment: you may also be interested in https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/365590/26948

Comment: @Henry By that, how do we know how $C_x$ is defined? Won't choosing $C$ affect $C_x$. Can't it be like, we choose a function $C_x$ for which $C = avg(C_x)$? This is what's making me believe that assumption 1 is always true.